# Could I lose reputation on Meta Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, reputation, down-votes, meta, per-site-meta

When I look at "Meta Stack Overflow" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/, I see many users asking good and bad questions, but I noticed that users asking bad questions who got downvoted don't seem to lose any reputation at all. Is it normal or do the downvotes and upvotes in this need to be validated by a moderator?

Comment: Why did you not ask this on MSO?

Comment: I got the answers below, but the site asked me to wait 7 min to accept an answer, thank you for the tip :p

Comment: Free advice: as already Catija showed, some user may see this question to be "off-topic" here and probably downvote/vote to close based on that. You  probably could avoid that by making it more generic: instead of just asking about MSO, try to expand the question to include the other site specific meta sites. As you already saw, the answer is still the same, but the question now *does* consider the network as a whole.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reputation on the per-site metas are inherited from the main site. So on Stack Overflow I have 66K reputation, on Meta Stack Overflow I have the exact same amount (it is synced one a while, so it is not totally accurate at all time).

So voting on the per-site meta doesn't bring you any reputation, nor you will lose any. You will only receive badges on posts on the votes (like Nice Question, Motarboard, etc.).

Voting is anonymous, so moderators have no intervention in validating votes, unless someone is suspected to be serial voting for example.

Answer (score 7):

No, you cannot lose reputation on a child meta (that is a meta that has a main site - like Meta Stack Overflow that has Stack Overflow).

The reputation on a child meta is inherited from the main site and is synced from it every now and then.

Now, by asking on a child meta, you may get more people looking at your main account and this, indirectly can cause reputation loss/gain, aka the meta effect.